# Detect patterns in data set

Tags: r, statistics

Given a data set with several records, that are similar to this one:

[image]

I want to detect the green dots. This pattern is recurring in a lot of the data records but is not completely identical (sd, variance, min, max etc). This data points are near the minimum and are showing a low variance.

I tried clustering (kmeans, dbscan, mclust) but the result was not very good.
How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Dare I say a simple threshold based on the minimum and a percentage?

Comment: Actually thats true, but the interesting points vary in mean and sd for each data record. Additionally the maximum peaks are different for each data record. Therefore ists difficult to detect this percentage accurately... Thats the reason why I want to use a "more intelligent" approach...